# How to efficiently generate all interleavings of lists in Haskell?

Tags: performance, haskell, generator, combinatorics

What's the most efficient way to generate all lists obtained by interleaving the elements of a given list of lists in Haskell?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/41929156 proposes the following code:

```hs
interleavings :: [[a]] -> [[a]]
interleavings = go . filter (not . null)
  where
    go [] = [[]]
    go xss = do
      (xssl, x : xs, xssr) <- zippers xss
      (x :) <$> interleavings ([xs | not (null xs)] ++ xssl ++ xssr)
    zippers :: [a] -> [([a], a, [a])]
    zippers = go' []
      where
        go' l (h : r) = (l, h, r) : go' (h : l) r
        go' _ [] = []
```

```hs
ghci> interleavings [[1,2,3],[4,5],[6]]
[[1,2,3,4,5,6],[1,2,3,4,6,5],[1,2,3,6,4,5],[1,2,4,5,3,6],[1,2,4,5,6,3],[1,2,4,3,5,6],[1,2,4,3,6,5],[1,2,4,6,3,5],[1,2,4,6,5,3],[1,2,6,4,5,3],[1,2,6,4,3,5],[1,2,6,3,4,5],[1,4,5,2,3,6],[1,4,5,2,6,3],[1,4,5,6,2,3],[1,4,2,3,5,6],[1,4,2,3,6,5],[1,4,2,5,3,6],[1,4,2,5,6,3],[1,4,2,6,5,3],[1,4,2,6,3,5],[1,4,6,2,3,5],[1,4,6,2,5,3],[1,4,6,5,2,3],[1,6,4,5,2,3],[1,6,4,2,3,5],[1,6,4,2,5,3],[1,6,2,3,4,5],[1,6,2,4,5,3],[1,6,2,4,3,5],[4,5,1,2,3,6],[4,5,1,2,6,3],[4,5,1,6,2,3],[4,5,6,1,2,3],[4,1,2,3,5,6],[4,1,2,3,6,5],[4,1,2,5,3,6],[4,1,2,5,6,3],[4,1,2,6,5,3],[4,1,2,6,3,5],[4,1,5,2,3,6],[4,1,5,2,6,3],[4,1,5,6,2,3],[4,1,6,5,2,3],[4,1,6,2,3,5],[4,1,6,2,5,3],[4,6,1,2,3,5],[4,6,1,2,5,3],[4,6,1,5,2,3],[4,6,5,1,2,3],[6,4,5,1,2,3],[6,4,1,2,3,5],[6,4,1,2,5,3],[6,4,1,5,2,3],[6,1,2,3,4,5],[6,1,2,4,5,3],[6,1,2,4,3,5],[6,1,4,5,2,3],[6,1,4,2,3,5],[6,1,4,2,5,3]]
```

This is useful for instance for concurrent tests that try out [all interleaving](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/77721/number-of-instruction-interleaving) of program instructions.

But is there a more efficient way to do this considering Haskell's lazy evaluation, and the fact that we are using singly-linked lists? What if we didn't need the entire result in memory at the same time, but we instead just needed to evaluate a function on each interleaving?

Comment: The code isn't per se eager, I would be surprised if it is not lazy. I'm not convinced that the entire result is always in memory.

Comment: I tried `for_ (interleavings (replicate 20 <$> [1..20])) (print . sum)` + `ghc -O2`. It happily prints out 4200 over and over for as long as I care to wait, never going above about 6KiB residency. So the quoted code may already meet your needs. (Conflict of interest declaration: I am the author of said code.)

Comment: Thanks, Daniel, your code is certainly clean and elegant, but I was hoping I could get it to run a bit faster? On a fairly beefy MacBook Pro `length $ interleavings $ replicate n [1 .. n]` takes 20s for `n = 4` (answer is `63063000` so there's probably no point trying `n = 5`...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make it slightly (33% in my tests) faster by using arrays arrays.

Setup:

```hs
-- Main.hs
import Data.Primitive.SmallArray
import Data.Primitive.PrimArray
import Data.Primitive (Prim)
import Control.Monad

smallToPrim :: Prim b => (a -> b) -> SmallArray a -> PrimArray b
smallToPrim f xs = runPrimArray $ do
  let n = length xs
  s <- newPrimArray n
  let
    go i 
      | i < n = do
        writePrimArray s i (f (indexSmallArray xs i))
        go (i + 1)
      | otherwise = pure ()
  go 0
  pure s

-- creates a new array where the ith element is one more than in the given array
increment :: Int -> PrimArray Int -> PrimArray Int
increment i xs = runPrimArray $ do
  let n = sizeofPrimArray xs
  s <- newPrimArray n
  copyPrimArray s 0 xs 0 n
  x <- readPrimArray s i
  writePrimArray s i (x + 1)
  return s
```

Main function:

```
interleavings :: SmallArray (SmallArray a) -> [[a]]
interleavings inputs = go id zeros where

  -- To compute all interleavings for an array [xs0, xs1, ..., xsn] we start
  -- with an array of indices that are all initialised to 0. Then we
  -- iteratively pick an index, add the next element from that input array to
  -- the current interleaving and increment the index. We repeat that until we
  -- have added all the elements from the input lists to the interleaving.  To
  -- get all possible interleavings we pick the index nondeterministically
  -- using the list monad.

  n = length inputs
  zeros = replicatePrimArray n 0
  end = smallToPrim length inputs

  -- acc is the particular interleaving we are working on right now
  go !acc !indices
    | indices == end = [acc []] 
    | otherwise = do -- list monad for nondeterminism
      -- pick one of the indices
      i <- [0 .. n - 1]
      let j = indexPrimArray indices i
      -- make sure that its index is within bounds
      guard (j < indexPrimArray end i)
      -- select that element from the input
      let !x = indexSmallArray (indexSmallArray inputs i) j
      -- add the element to the current interleaving and increment the corresponding index
      go (acc . (x :)) (increment i indices)
```

Test and benchmark:

```
test :: [[Int]]
test = [[1,2,3],[4,5],[6]] 

bench :: [[Int]]
bench = replicate 4 [1 :: Int .. 4]

main :: IO ()
main = print $ length $ interleavings $ smallArrayFromList $ map smallArrayFromList bench
```

Compile with `ghc -O2 Main.hs`

Result:

```
$ ./Main +RTS -s
63063000
  89,190,505,480 bytes allocated in the heap
      34,217,632 bytes copied during GC
          44,328 bytes maximum residency (4 sample(s))
          29,400 bytes maximum slop
               6 MiB total memory in use (0 MiB lost due to fragmentation)

                                     Tot time (elapsed)  Avg pause  Max pause
  Gen  0     21419 colls,     0 par    0.046s   0.049s     0.0000s    0.0000s
  Gen  1         4 colls,     0 par    0.000s   0.000s     0.0001s    0.0001s

  INIT    time    0.000s  (  0.000s elapsed)
  MUT     time    8.872s  (  8.864s elapsed)
  GC      time    0.046s  (  0.049s elapsed)
  EXIT    time    0.000s  (  0.006s elapsed)
  Total   time    8.918s  (  8.920s elapsed)

  %GC     time       0.0%  (0.0% elapsed)

  Alloc rate    10,053,049,984 bytes per MUT second

  Productivity  99.5% of total user, 99.4% of total elapsed
```

Comment: Cool! I was wondering if arrays would make this more efficient. I’m afraid I couldn’t understand your code very well, would it be possible to add some comments or explain the high-level algorithm? Thanks!

Comment: Also, what tool did you use to measure performance?

Comment: @psquid I've added comments now, I hope it is clearer this way. Feel free to ask questions about specific parts. I measure performance simply by using the `+RTS -s` runtime option, see https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/9.6.2/docs/users_guide/runtime_control.html#rts-options-to-produce-runtime-statistics.

Comment: To make this truly fast you would want to remove all allocations. That means you should not generate a list of interleavings, but do whatever you want to do with each interleaving inside the function. And secondly instead of using `increment` you'd want to do an in-place update. I think that could yield a 10x performance improvement.